# Using second init/systemd startup on different partition

Tags: systemd, startup, init

We have the following setup:

- A read-only system partition from which the kernel is booted from. (Debian Jessie)
- A read-write partition which has additional software to be started as daemons.
- A simple custom startup script on the r/w partition to start the daemons. This script is started as last service from the systemd on the r/o partition.

How can I leverage a modern init variant (systemd/init/initng/...) to (independently from the r/o systemd) start the stuff on the r/w partition?

Comment: You could configure a container which will be launched by your "ro-root-system". The container can have its root on the rw-partition. Alternatively you could just write systemd units for each daemon.

Comment: @sebasth The system is too resource-constraint for a container. And I can't plug the daemons into the regular systemd because of the read-only nature of the system-partition.

Comment: LXC containers are quite lightweight using Linux namespaces (mount, PID, network, ...). You can avoid having redundant system files by configuring bind mounts to common binaries and other common files. Your init system would need its own configuration, but if necessary you can also bind mount them to `/etc` in your container's namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an overlay mount
to act on both sets of startup scripts transparently,
with the caveat that services specified on the RW partition
shadow those on the RO one.

Suppose for concreteness in this description
that you are using `systemd`,
that the RO partition is the root partition, and
that the RW partition is mounted at `/rw` and contains two directories,
`systemd` and `work`.
You can do an overlay mount as follows:

```
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/etc/systemd,upperdir=/rw/systemd,workdir=/rw/work overlay /etc/systemd
```

This can be specified in `/etc/fstab`:

```
# Previous fstab entries to ensure /rw is mounted
overlay /etc/systemd overlay lowerdir=/etc/systemd,upperdir=/rw/systemd,workdir=/rw/work 0 0
```

With this `fstab` entry the two directories will be merged at boot
and will appear to `systemd` (and everything else)
as a single set of startup scripts.
Attempts to write to `/etc/systemd` will be redirected to the RW partition.

This method isn't specific to `systemd`.  It generalizes to any init system that acts on the contents of some directory.

Comment: If I read documentation correctly, this method cannot work since fstab is loaded by systemd itself and the order of unit booting is determined when systemd starts. This way everything located on the rw partition will not be available when systemd starts and thus won't start.

Comment: if that's true, there's a hack for that: have a single startup script on the ro portion that depends on fstab being loaded, calls daemon-reload, then re-switches to the default target

Comment: Would it be possible to outline this hack in more detail?